# Implementation of OOP for retrieving list of objects from database

Tags: c#, object-oriented, classes, database, beginner

If I have a `Person` class that outlines the properties of a person and one of `People` that just contains a `List<Person>` like so:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(){}
    public int personID {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string address {get;set;}
}

public class People
{
    public People(){}

    public List<Person> peoples {get;set;}

    public List<Person> getPeople()
    {
        List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
        //create database connection
        //open datareader

        Person onePerson = new Person();
        //write data to eahc property type and add data to list

        p.Add(onePerson);
        return p;
    }
}
```

To call the database method that gets the people from the database I could do this:

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
    People p = new People();
    p.getPeople();
}
```

Is this how I would do this in terms of OOP?

I'm just beginning to use these techniques in my coding as usually I would remove the `getPeople()` method from the `People` class and do this in `main()`:

```
static void main(string[] args)
{
    List<Person> people = getPeople();
}

private static List<Person> getPeople()
{
    List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
    //create database connection
    //open datareader
    //load data into list

    Person onePerson = new Person();

    p.Add(onePerson);
    return p;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the point of those empty public constructors...

Comment: `peoples` is a rather confusing name for a `List<Person>`, especially in a class called `People`.

Comment: Since it's a code review site: your code is tagged as C# and looks like Java. Method names should start with upper case, same goes for properties.

Comment: @Migol YESSS!!! I'm not the only one!! (been biting my tongue on this one)

Answer (score 5):

Very few things in life are free. C# default constructors are one of those, the compiler generates one automatically for you if your class doesn't explicitly have one! So unless you have another constructor (with parameters) and you also *need* a parameterless one, putting it in is just clutter.

Encapsulating database operations in a dedicated object (like you're doing with your `People` class), vs doing it all in a `static` method, is a step forward in the right direction.. but I don't see what the `peoples` property is trying to encapsulate.

Think of classes as **abstractions** - you have a `Person` abstraction which represents a single record in your database. Then you have a `People` abstraction which represents an object that can manipulate `Person` records. That's all nice and tidy and high-level - you don't want to mix this niceness with **boilerplate-level SQL connections** and queries. Doing that is writing code *at the wrong level of abstraction*.

So the next step forward would be to create *another class* that's responsible for dealing with these things - a type that would deal with setting up a connection, running a query and then disposing the connection and every other `IDiposable` along the way.

Once you've done that, you will (hopefully) realize you've just reinvented the wheel - and that your wheel is more than likely square. **At this stage it's all good**, the worst thing you could do is *start with* an Entity Data Model that does it all for you: you want to *understand* what's going on, if it feels *automagic* then you've skipped something.

So first (well, after you've written your square wheel!) take a look at **Linq to SQL** and see what a `DataContext` can do for you.

Comment: So I should have the getPeople() defined in the People class?

Comment: I see your `People` class as some sort of `Person` *repository* whose job is to perform data operations on `Person`, so yes - and then you'll want to add some `AddPerson`, `RemovePerson` and `UpdatePerson` methods, too - they all belong in there :)

Comment: But the `People.peoples` property is wrong though; if the job of `People` is to perform data operations, keeping a copy of the records is breaking this *single responsibility* - and I'm not even mentioning the public setter!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think the better approach would be this:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(){}
    public int personID {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string address {get;set;}

    public static List<Person> GetPeople() { }
}
```

Now to get a list of `Person` objects, you just do this:

```
var people = Person.GetPeople();
```

And just get rid of the `People` class. It isn't really doing anything. In fact, you're just building a new data structure when the `List<T>` is perfect already.

---

Alright, in light of the comments on this post, let me dig a little deeper for you on this one.

I believe the approach I'd take goes much further than the aforementioned simplified solution. So, let's get started. The first thing I'd do is include [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). This is available via NuGet.

The next thing I'd do is build a static method to wrap the work that needs to be done with Dapper to ensure proper use of resources. That might look like this:

```
using Dapper;

public static class DatabaseAccess
{
    private static string _connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"];

    public static IEnumerable<T> Query<T>(string cmd,
        string filter = null,
        object parameters = null)
    {
        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(_connString))
        {
            return c.Query<T>(string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, filter),
                parameters);
        }
    }

    public static T Single<T>(string cmd,
        string filter = null,
        object parameters = null)
    {
        return Query<T>(cmd, filter, parameters).Single();
    }
}
```

Alright, now that we've got a way to get to the database, let's fix up that POCO a little:

```
public class Person
{
    private const string _selectCmd = "SELECT personID, name, address FROM Person";

    public int personID {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string address {get;set;}

    public static List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        return DatabaseAccess.Query<Person>(_selectCmd).ToList();
    }

    public static Person GetPerson(int id)
    {
        return DatabaseAccess.Single<Person>(_selectCmd,
            "WHERE personID = @ID",
            new { ID = id });
    }
}
```

and so now to use this, you just do this still:

```
var list = Person.GetPeople();
```

or to get one:

```
var p = Person.GetPerson(1);
```

Now, I could take this even further by using attributes, reflection, and dynamic SQL generation; but I just feel that's probably outside the scope of this post.

Comment: ...and put all the data access code in `Person` as well? Along with an eventual `SaveChanges()` or `Delete()` method? I don't think that's right...

Comment: @retailcoder, absolutely. Who else knows how to `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, or `INSERT` a `Person`? Now, I could recommend a more dynamic solution that leverages attributing, reflection, dynamic SQL creation, and Dapper; but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I don't agree, a DTO/POCO shouldn't be *doing* anything. The *context* knows about the database, and in this case the closest thing would be `People` - you're coupling POCO's with the database and turning an eventual upgrade to EF into a nightmare! (ok, a delete-all-that-code party!) What am I missing here? I mean, you're among the top 0.26% StackOverflow users, there's gotta be something I missed!

Comment: @retailcoder, first I'm not big on EF. It's bloated and dictates too much. Second, I'm not big on context objects either because they are generally misused (e.g. don't leverage `using` statements) and are heavy. I prefer Dapper over all solutions, and even in this solution, I'd use Dapper internally to actually `SELECT` the data. Now, odds are I'd end up building an extension method on `IDbConnection` to house the actual ADO work and so the method would just about be a one-liner. But the OP is just getting started here; and complicating that with a bloated OO design won't help.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/ never used that. Looks nice, especially if you're after performance.

Comment: @retailcoder, have a look at my edit. I'm going to keep working on it a bit - but I think you'll get the idea.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11359/discussion-between-retailcoder-and-neoistheone)

Comment: +1 for the effort :) ...and I'm going to look into this Dapper.NET thing, too!